# FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 41: File does not exist at path (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, filereader

I am trying to read the uploaded file to my system but I can't be able to read it because every time I do it I get this error `FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 41: File does not exist at path /var/www/html/..` I dont know what am I doing wrong in it. I am using `File::get()` method. Below is the code. Thanks for the help

```
public function getUploadedFile() {

    $destinationPath = 'uploads';
    $path= public_path()."/". $destinationPath;

    echo $path; // this was to check whether am I getting the right path or not which I am getting.

    $upload = new Upload; 
    $content = utf8_encode(File::get($path ."/". $upload->file_name));
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: is your file permission is 644 and folder permission 077.check once and also once provide full path of the file and check

Comment: Why you are doing this ?

    `$upload = new Upload; 
    $content = utf8_encode(File::get($path ."/". $upload->file_name));
    return $content;`
Why not just simply return the `$path` to the view and display it!

Comment: how to do that with word files ? I mean every word file will be having different text, font, etc ?

Comment: I mean what should be the view look alike to display the word or pdf files ? I have one to download excel files but dont know how to use all these together ?

Comment: I tried this piece of code too but this is just giving me a blank page and nothing else
            `$file_name = File::get($file_name);
            $response = Response::make($file_name, 200);
          
           $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel);
    
            return $response;
        }`

Comment: `$content_types = [
                'application/octet-stream', // txt etc
                'application/msword', // doc
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', //docx
                'application/vnd.ms-excel', // xls
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', // xlsx
                'application/pdf', // pdf
            ];`

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
public function setFileAttribute($file){
$this->attributes['file'] = Carbon::now()->second.$file->getClientOriginalName();
$name = Carbon::now()->second.$file->getClientOriginalName(); 
\Storage::disk('local')->put($name, \File::get($file));
    }
```

**fileSystems.php**

```
   'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
       // 'root' => storage_path('public'),
        'root' => public_path('storage'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('storage'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => 'your-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret',
        'region' => 'your-region',
        'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
    ],

],
```

Comment: Please add some comments and description in your code snippet.